# Calculate the viewport rectangle of a zoomed/scrolled canvas

Tags: c#, .net, gdi, viewport

I have a custom control that is displaying a canvas image.  I'm using AutoScroll and also a zoom ratio to display the image.

Therefore the data I have to work with are:

- Zoom scale ratio (2.0f = 200% zoom)
- Canvas bounds (RectangleF).  An image that's 800x600px will have a CanvasBounds of 1600x1200 with a 2.0f zoom ratio.  The Location point is the starting point of the canvas if it is zoomed out and not scrolling.
- ClientRectangle
- AutoScrollPosition

I need to calculate the Viewport at any given time, given in coordinates relative to the original bitmap.  So if the entire image is visible, and the image is 800x600, then the Viewport would be a Rectangle at 0,0 with a size of 800,600.

I'm zoomed on the image, the Viewport should always be the rectangle representing the entire visible area.  If I'm zoomed out and the image is centered on the screen then the viewport should be the entire image.

---

EDIT: Here is a graphical representation.  The bitmap is currently zoomed, but I have the original size and the ratio at which it is zoomed.  And I have the AutoScrollPosition.  The AutoScrollMinSize is set depending on the zoom level.  If the image height is 500px and we're at 200% (2.0f) zoom, then the AutoScrollMinSize.Height is 1000.

The red box would represent the Viewport rectangle.

[image]

Comment: I don't have an answer in C#, but take a look at Appendix A of http://compsci.gxstudios.net/project.pdf in case it helps.

Comment: This isn't 3D, it's GDI+

Comment: The appendix isn't talking about 3D, it was for a 2D design canvas in a 3D map editor.

Comment: Oh, ok, I had searched for "Viewport" in the document and didn't find the word.  I'll take another look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  Here is the code that I got to work for me.

In this solution, AutoScrollMinSize is equal to CanvasBounds.Size.  First I check if the window is bigger than the canvas, in which case I know the entire bitmap is visible and return that as the viewport.  Otherwise, I calculate it by converting the screen pixels to bitmap pixels.

```
public RectangleF Viewport
{
    get
    {
        if (AutoScrollMinSize.Width <= ClientRectangle.Width && AutoScrollMinSize.Height < ClientRectangle.Height)
        {
            return BitmapRectF;
        }
        else
        {
            return new RectangleF(
                Math.Abs(AutoScrollPosition.X / _ratio),
                Math.Abs(AutoScrollPosition.Y / _ratio),
                Math.Min(CanvasBounds.Width / _ratio, ClientRectangle.Width / _ratio),
                Math.Min(CanvasBounds.Height / _ratio, ClientRectangle.Height / _ratio)
            );
        }
    }
}
```